# Не могу настроить цикл

Tags: python, if, while

Использую библиотеку Tesseract для обнаружения символов на картинке. Нужно чтобы при обнаружении "1" выводилось "НАЖИМАЮ" пока не появится "2". Но при обнаружении "1" оно сваливается в цикл и больше не ищет ничего. Помогите пожалуйста мозгов на большее не хватает -_-.

```
def search():
        if re.findall(r'1', text):
            while(True):
                print('НАЖИМАЮ')
        if re.findall(r'2', text)
                print('ОТЖИМАЮ')
```

Comment: Прочитайте про цикл `while`, а также про операторы `break` и `continue`. Иначе подобные проблемы постоянно будут.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас просто при нажатии `1` включаеться бесконечный цыкл, из за этого программа уже не считывает 2. Вот Вам код который должен сработать!:

```
def search():
    if re.findall(r'1', text):
        while(True):
            print('НАЖИМАЮ')
            if re.findall(r'2', text)
                print('ОТЖИМАЮ')
                break
```

Answer (score -1):

При обнаружении двойки бесконечный цикл будет останавливаться.

```py
def search():
    while True:
        if re.findall(r'1', text):
            print('НАЖИМАЮ')
        if re.findall(r'2', text):
            print('ОТЖИМАЮ')
            break
```